# How to respond to a ul li click in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following unordered list embedded in a Bootstrap Panel. The user adds items to this dynamically at runtime.

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2 panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">Species Seen</div>
            <div class="panel-body" style="height: 400px; overflow:auto">
                <ul id="speciesAdded" class="list-group">
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to respond to a user clicking one of the items via jQuery:

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
        $('ul#speciesAdded li').click(function () {
            alert($(this).text());
        });
    })
```

It seems I don't have something wired right because the alert never displays.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since your list items is not exist when the page is created, all the events will not be available to these elements, in this case you need to apply **[event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)** in order to attach event to these newly added list items:

```
$('#speciesAdded').on('click','li',function () {
    alert($(this).text());
});
```